# How to increase Animation Duration on every click in JS?

Tags: javascript

**CSS**

```
#plus{ animation-duration: 5s;}
```

**I want to increase it on every click using JavaScript...**

**JS Code**

```
var increasePlus = document.getElementById("plus");  
increasePlus.addEventListener('click', () => {
var sec= 5 + "s";    
if(sec=="5s"){
   sec = 6 + "s";
   increasePlus.style.animationDuration = sec;
}   
if(sec=="6s"){
   sec = 7 + "s";
   increasePlus.style.animationDuration = sec;
}   
});
```

It doesn't work !!!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This makes it from 5s to 3s for animation-duration those if conditions will always be true for both of them. I'm confused why you think this would increase the duration.

Comment: sorry sir, i am still confused please check the question again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the logic of the given code we can see that the animation-duration is always set to the same amount (7s) on every click - it never changes after the first click:

```
var increasePlus = document.getElementById("plus");  
increasePlus.addEventListener('click', () => {
var sec= 5 + "s";    
if(sec=="5s"){//this is always true as sec has just been set to 5s
   sec = 6 + "s";//so sec is set to 6s
   increasePlus.style.animationDuration = sec;
}   
if(sec=="6s"){//this is always true as sec has (just) been set to 6s
   sec = 7 + "s";//so sec is now set to 7s
   increasePlus.style.animationDuration = sec;//and so the animation-duration is ALWAYS set to 7s on a click
}   
});
```

It is difficult to click on a moving object which is what the given code seems to require (the clickable element id plus is also the one given the animation duration in that code) so in this snippet the plus element gets clicked and that updates the animation duration of a separate object which is the one that moves.

```js
    const increasePlus = document.getElementById("plus");
    const theObject = document.getElementById('object');
        
    increasePlus.addEventListener('click', () => {

    //get the current animation-duration
    //remember this has an s at the end so we need to get rid of that so we can add to it
    let sec= window.getComputedStyle(theObject, null)["animationDuration"].replace('s','');
    //add 1 to it
    sec++;
    //and set the animation-duration
    theObject.style.animationDuration = sec + 's';   
    });
```

```css
#plus{
  font-size: 60px;
}

#object {
  position: relative;  
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: magenta;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 30vh;
  }
}
```

```html
  <button id="plus">+</button> 
  <div id="object"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir it works. #Perfectly              #Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can fail because of this line

```
var sec= 5 + "s";
```

this line will execute always when you click on the button, so after that in "if" condition you will always get sec = '5s' and than it will be decreased to '4s'.

If you want that code to work, you could place "var sec = 5+'s' above the listener declaration.